# Database error with MariaDB/Django. Why is it asking if I installed mysqlclient?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mariadb

EDIT: This is Ubuntu 18.04 and my working version was also on 18.04

I recently did a database wipe on my django 2.2.7 python 3 project. The why is because I switched PC's and wanted a fresh MariaDB install. But I think this pc had some stuff already on it so here's what I did:

I followed the instructions on this page https://mariadb.com/kb/en/uninstall-or-delete-mariadb-completely-for-re-installation/

First uninstalling and then checking the packages installed as instructed and I deleted those too.

Then I followed this instruction to install https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mariadb-on-ubuntu-18-04

However now that I am trying to fill the database using my django code (that used to work just fine). I'm getting the following error when running python3 manage.py makemigrations:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: libmariadbclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

I have tried many steps to remedy this. Mostly involving installing various packages such as pymysql. From a google search it seems to me that mysqlclient may not be python3 compatible? I know for a fact that I was using django 2.2.7 before the switch which means I had to have been using python 3 as it's the only one compatible. So I'm pretty sure it's not a version mismatch. Anyone got a clue?

UPDATE: I had mysqlclient installed already. But I still get the same error mentioned above. I've checked and my pip is pip for python 3.6:

```
 pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

So it's asking me if I have installed mysqlclient. I can now answer YES to that. But I'm no closer to solving this

UPDATE2: To anyone who has a working MariaDB implementation. Could I compare my packages to yours? This is what `sudo dpkg -l | grep mariadb` returns for me:

```
ii  mariadb-client-10.1                    1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                      amd64        MariaDB database client binaries
ii  mariadb-client-core-10.1               1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                      amd64        MariaDB database core client binaries
ii  mariadb-common                         1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                      all          MariaDB common metapackage
ii  mariadb-server                         1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                      all          MariaDB database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mariadb-server-10.1                    1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                      amd64        MariaDB database server binaries
ii  mariadb-server-core-10.1               1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                      amd64        MariaDB database core server files
```

Comment: mysqlclient is supported on py3.6-3.9 (https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/)

Comment: Ok so I actually already had that installed. Will update my question